# how to select a specific entry from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, string

```
string: {"foo1":"1123","foo2":"332","foo3":"23-SEP-15"}
```

Hi Guys,

Im attempting to retrieve the value of foo3 from a string (so need the date part of the string). Ive tried parsing this with JSON but seems to throw up a lot of difficulties in my program if the date string is in the incorrect format (which is a possibility).

Was thinking it might be easier to put this into an array and then search the array for date matches?

Or would it be easier just to search the actual string itself for the date (or i guess any string after foo3: and enclosed in " ".

My regex is extremely poor so im really struggling to do this method myself. Any advice on which technique would be best would be really appreciated

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: There should be no problem parsing this as JSON. What "incorrect format" may your date be in and what problems does that "throw up"?

Comment: Could you post an example of an incorrectly formatted string? (Also, not everyone here is a "guy" ;))

Comment: @georg "Guys" usually denotes a group of people of either/any sex.

Comment: As you have it formatted above that is not a string but an object. As such you can access the value of `foo3` by using `string.foo3` or `string['foo3']`. If that is just an example format you should add the exact way your code is. Explicit is good when asking questions. You can also check the validity of your JSON here - http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: apologies guys and gals, i use the unisex "guys" :) so if foo3 doesnt exist at all, the parse will return null and this throws exceptions. Ive tried capturing this as an error with limited success (think my knowledge just isnt good enough!) so thought easiest method would be to search the string itself for the section i need and return this to its own variable

Comment: also that is the exact way the string looks when within a variable. Im capturing the entire string from a cookie

Comment: How exactly are you "parsing JSON" to throw an error with a non-existent key? Show your code and your exact error.

Comment: Try `var text = '{"foo1":"1123","foo2":"332","foo4":"23-SEP-15"}';
var dataArray = JSON.parse(text, function(k,v){
   if (k === 'foo3') { document.write(v); }
});
`. If there is no `foo3`, it will not be output.

Comment: Right, if there is no foo3, it will not be output... 1) That's not an "error" and 2) what else did you expect to happen...?

Comment: @stribizhev This seems to be working, could you break down how this works a little bit? Ive not come across this method before

Comment: @deceze sorry, I didnt explain this issue very well.. if i have any further problems ill post the entire code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the value of `foo3`, you can just use [`JSON.Parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) with a callback function that will only return the value of `foo3` if it is present.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var text = '{"foo1":"1123","foo2":"332","foo3":"23-SEP-15"}';
JSON.parse(text, function(k,v){
  if (k === 'foo3') {
    document.write(v);
  }
  return v; 
});
```

Here, in `function(k,v)`, `k` stands for the key and `v` stands for the value.
You can find more working examples of how to parse JSON with JavaScript at the provided MDN link above.

Comment: that's fantastic, thanks a lot. Saved me no end of hassle with this issue. Again apologies for the vagueness of the question, ill alter the title slightly so at least it will be of use to other users